# Изучение чужого кода. Как?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Большой проект на 2000+ файлов. Пытался составить диаграмму зависимостей в VS2013, но что-то не строит её из-за ошибок. Подскажите, какие средства и инструменты можно использовать, что бы разобраться в структуре проекта.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно просто иметь общее представление о том, что делает проект, и что делают его основные составные части. То есть нужно иметь понимание на верхнем уровне абстракции данного проекта, что он делает, и как он устроен.

Для этого, естественно, необходимо познакомиться с его описанием и соответствующей документацией.

Что касается изучения кода, то код имеет смысл изучать лишь тот, с которым вы имеете непосредственно дело. То есть, например, если вам надо внести изменения в какой-нибудь модуль, то вы и изучаете те функции модуля, которые потенциально связаны с изменениями. Желательно иметь связь с тем программистом, который ранее писал этот модуль или по крайней мере вносил в модуль ту логику, которую вам предстоит изменить, или с программистом, который имеет более глубокое понимание о структуре проекта и о его функциональности.

Когда вы внесете изменения в модуль, то вы сами станете уже специалистом по этому модулю и его функциональности.:)

Для таких больших проектов каждый программист является узким специалистом за исключением тех программистов, которые являются архитекторами проекта. И в принципе даже нет необходимости знать, что делает весь проект. Достаточно знать узкий круг тех специализированных задач, с которыми вы имеете дело в той части проекта, на которую вас нацелили.

Представьте себе: есть проект разработки Windows. Как программисту вам на самом деле достаточно знать всего лишь, что Windows - это операционная система.:) А вы сами будете, например, отвечать за разработку проводника, и в самом проводнике - за его графический интерфейс.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Проект брошен, документации 0, вот пытаюсь создать средствами VS2013  карту кода, для лучшего понимания архитектуры.

Comment: @alexgdi Извините, я не понимаю, как проект в более, чем 2000 файлов, может быть брошен, если вы конечно не преувеличиваете число файлов? Это лишь говорит о том, что вы имеете дело с какими-то проходимцами, с которыми не следует иметь дело.